# How to get specific part of output with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I need to get specific part of output from a bash script. I have a bash script which already shows the location of json file but I also need username of owner of json file.

I have tried `cat userswithjson.txt | grep -o '/home/*'` but it didn't work.

```sh
files=$(find /home -name file.json -print)
echo "$files" >> userswithjson.txt
cat userswithjson | grep -o '/home/*'
```

Expected output: `user` Actual output: `/home/user/file.json`

Content of `userswithjson.txt`: `/home/user/file.json`

Comment: Please show the contents of `userswithjson.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use awk to quickly parse your `userswithjson` file and output the userid portion of the file path.  Here's some code that will achieve that for you:

```
awk -F/ '{print $3}' userswithjson
```

The `-F/` sets the IFS (input field separator) for awk.  Awk breaks each input line into fields based on the IFS. The fields are given numeric names (like `$3`).

Answer (score 0):

files could be under `/home/some-user` and belong to **another-user**. So if you want to get the name of the file owner, you could:

```
stat -c '%U' /path/to/your/file
```

which I got [here](https://ma.ttias.be/get-the-file-or-directory-owner-in-bash-for-use-in-scripts-on-linux/)

You could then simplify your script like this:

```
for file in $(find /home -name file.json -print)
do
    owner=$(stat -c '%U' $file)
    echo "$owner : $file"
done
```

Comment: It gives output root for /home/user/file.json I need output which username have file in their ~/

Comment: which proves what I say: it is not because a file is under /home/user that it really belongs to that user. This shows that the user **root** has created the file under /home/user... it also depends on what you want to obtain with your script: the real file owner or not?

Comment: Not real owner, I just need file is located at home directory of which user.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks a lot for your help! And I gave a upvote but I have less than 15 reputation so it's not casted.